# Multiple records per case

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create such query:

```
select *
from ...
stageid IN  (CASE WHEN o.someotherId= (@predefinedId) 
                            THEN (N'here is guid actually',N'another guid') 
                            ELSE (N'and here is a guid',N'+ guid')
                       END)
```

it doesn't compile, but if I leave just 1 guid per case it'll compile but won't solve my task.

what could be done to return multiple records per case?

Comment: Nothing is clear from your question. Format your tried query and then add the dummy data with expected resultset. And specify which DBMS you are using.

Comment: Post the full query and add the error message detail to your question.

Comment: Of course it wont compile. What the hell are you trying to do?

Comment: Using CASE inside an IN clause is quite odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wish to do like this:

```
where (o.someotherId = (@predefinedId) and stageid IN (...))
    or (o.someotherId != (@predefinedId) and stageid IN (...))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `OR` instead of `CASE`:

```
... (
    (o.someotherId = (@predefinedId) AND stageid IN (N'here is guid actually',N'another guid')) OR
    (o.someotherId <> (@predefinedId) AND stageid IN (N'and here is a guid',N'+ guid'))
)
```